# Lvlup Lu734 Pro Gaming Keyboard wont illuminate in the Graphical session

Tags: command-line, keyboard, hardware

I bought a Vivitar Lvlup Lu734 Pro Gaming Keyboard,
with RGB lights. the thing came with no instructions, but google says to press scroll lock
to turn on the lights.
So I do this, but while I am in a desktop session, it simply will not turn on the lights.
For giggles, I pressed ctrl+alt+F2, logged into a shell, and pressed scroll lock, and the lights came on instantly.

I'm trying to figure out what the difference here is.

When I switched back to the GUI, the lights went out.

Switched back to the shell, (didn't press anything) the lights came back on.

What? Is scroll lock treated differently in the shell?
Any ideas on how I can make this thing work in a graphical session?

Ubuntu Mate, 22.04

Why did I mark this post "command-line"? because it works when I'm in a shell.